# SQL primary/identity key is not autoincrementing

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2017

Hi I'm confused as to why SQL is not auto-incrementing my Id column when I'm passing a null value in the code:

```
case GameStatus.WIN:
                gamefeed.Items.Add(String.Format("Congragulations, you rolled {0}. YOU WIN.", Sum));

                connect.Open();
                SqlCommand cmdwin = connect.CreateCommand();
                cmdwin.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmdwin.CommandText = "insert into Round values('','" + textBox2.Text + "', '" + numRolls.ToString() + "', '"+ Point.ToString()+"', 'Win')";
                cmdwin.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connect.Close();

                break;
```

Any assistance or nudges towards the right direction is appreciated!

Comment: What database is this? SQL Server?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 17

Comment: It's better to tag this with the database and language involved than the tools you're using. VIsual Studio is a non-factor here. I've re-tagged so this is more likely to be noticed by people with expertise in those areas.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 2):

If you have defined your `Id` column as an `Identity` column, you do not need to pass anything for the `Id` column in your INSERT statement (not even a placeholder).

```
cmdwin.CommandText = 
    "insert into Round values('" + textBox2.Text + "', '" + numRolls.ToString() + "', '"+ Point.ToString()+"', 'Win')";
```

Also, please note it's a very bad idea to concatenate text values (SQL Injection), use Parameters instead.

Comment: I have just received this message "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.'"

Comment: post your table definition please.

Comment: @springathing You don't need to pass any value to the `Identity` column, SQL Server will take care of it ;-)

Comment: I had to recreate the table and set the Identity column at time of creation for it to work

Comment: @springathing: that doesn't make any sense; An identity column has to be defined when the table is created!

Comment: @Mitch Wheat My identity value was blank when I checked, and after setting it to Id I tried saving it but it prompted me a message saying that I can't save my changes b/c this table can't be dropped and re-created. So after deleting the records and the table I recreated it manually setting Identity to Id

Answer (score 1):

As already said that you dont need to paas value to identity field (autoincrement)

Your SQL should be

```
"insert into Round values('" + textBox2.Text + "', '" + numRolls.ToString() + "', '"+ Point.ToString()+"', 'Win')";
```

If you are getting error

```
Column name or number does not match table definition
```

Then you either are passing more values in insert then your columns in table Round. 
OR
You should try giving names of your column in insert query

```
—Column1 is Identity
"insert into Round(Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5) values('" + textBox2.Text + "', '" + numRolls.ToString() + "', '"+ Point.ToString()+"', 'Win')";
/*Replace Column,2,3,4,5 with your respective columns in table Round*/
```